# Simple Ajax request with php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to pass a simple variable from my jQuery to my php and then echo it on my HTML. It doesn't seem to work though.

I can't get my variable $result to show up on my page. Any thoughts? The Ajax POST seems to be working fine. The problem seems to be communication between php and HTML.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>My Site</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='front.js'></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $result; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

front.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post('/back.php', {name: "Bob"}, function(data) {         
    });
});
```

back.php:

```
<?php $result = $_POST['name']; ?>
```

Comment: Have you include this back.php in your html file??

Comment: No, didn't realize I needed to. Can you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? All you do is hand over the value "Bob" to your PHP script and there you do a simple variable assignment. Nothing is going to be returned to the executing page and your result function doesn't do anything anyway.

Comment: For example, in htmlo file you have to inclede your back.php file before <?php echo $result; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>My Site</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='front.js'></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**front.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $.post('/back.php', {name: "Bob"}, function(result) {
        $('body').html(result);         
    });    
});
```

**back.php:**

```
<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<body>
    <div id="show-data"></div>
</body>
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.post('/back.php', {name: "Bob"}, function(data) {
        $('#show-data').html(data);         
    });

});
```

And

```
<?php echo $result = $_POST['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Change Your PHP Code :
<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>

And Also Your HTML Code :

    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head> 
                    <title>My Site</title>
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


            </head>
            <body>

            </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $.post('/back.php', {name: "Bob"}, function(data) {         
        $('body').append(data)});

    });  
    </script>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result` in back.php and `$result` in index.html aren't related.  Setting it in back.php has no effect on index.html.  If you echo something in back.php however, that output will be passed to the empty callback function you have in your $.post() call.  You can handle the data there and use javascript to insert it into your page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to your code: `$('body').html(data);`

Comment: Where in the code exactly? And he needs to echo data in back.php

Answer (score 0):

Like your question we have three different files one is index.html
1) index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>My Site</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='front.js'></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $result; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) front.js

```
$(document).load(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/back.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'name=Bob',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                    $('body').html(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
```

3) back.php

```
<?php echo $result = $_POST['name']; ?>
```

Now use this, your files will work out. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score -1):

Puh, lot of mistakes. First, your index.html contains PHP - Code which won't be executed because this is not a PHP - Skript (ending with php). 
Second you are saving the value of your request to back.php in a variable, which won't be existing after the request is finished. You can either:
rename index.html to index.php, exchange your statement to

```
<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
```

and change your request to

```
$.get('/index.php', {name: "Bob"}, function(data) {         
});
```

which would cause a continously reloading of the site,
or store your result in a $_SESSION (see PHP Session Handling), and retrieve that in your index.php (you got to rename the file).

Comment: You're sending data with $.get and receiving it with $.post. Ahhhh, Wrong.

Comment: Right, $_REQUEST or $_GET instead of $_POST